# call a function onclick a button in html5

Tags: javascript, android, html, touch

I want to call a function by touching a button in HTML5. I haveange in a canvas drawn a rect.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="as" type="button">Left</button></body>
<script>
    var inc=10;
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(x,0,150,75);
    function moveLeft(){ x+=inc }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. And? What is your question?

Comment: So what have you tried? Attaching event handlers is a too broad topic to be correctly taught on a Q&A site. You can expect some `c.onclick = moveLeft;` answers, but don't listen to them. Please read through this [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: i want to move canvas by touching on button.like ontouch.rectangle move by 10px

Comment: I recommend to read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html to learn the basics about events and event handling.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned 'touch', I guess we'll need a timer.  The canvas draw routine also need some fixing.  Here is my version:

```
<html><body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="300" style='border:1px solid black'></canvas>
<button id="as" type="button" onmouseover='startMove()' onmouseout='stopMove()'>Left</button></body>
<script>
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var inc = 10;
    var timer = 0;
    var x = 100;
    function moveLeft(){ if ( x > 0 ) x-=inc; drawCtx(); }
    function drawCtx(){ ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,300); ctx.fillStyle='black'; ctx.fillRect(x,0,50,75); }
    function startMove(){ stopMove(); timer = setInterval(moveLeft, 1000);  }
    function stopMove(){ clearInterval(timer); }
    drawCtx();
</script>
```

What this do is when you mouse over it will start calling moveLeft once per second (1000ms interval) until you move away the mouse.

Code is not nice, but it works and I hope it is simple enough to get the point across.

Comment: `touch` === `timer` ? I don't understand it

Comment: @pomeh: Not exactly. But I guess the intent is to move a box as long as the mouse keep touching the button, in which case we need an interval timer or some alternatives (such as the new requestAnimationFrame) to keep it moving.

Comment: Ok I see. Well, for me `touching a button` was more about touch events, but we don't have enough information about that know more. @LaxmiKant what is the intent ?

Comment: i want to move canvas by touching that button in mobile(Android)

Comment: @LaxmiKant: I see. Android is another matter, this is an important point that should be marked in the question (and tagged) as well.  I haven't tried but if mouseover/mouseout doesn't work you can try those real touch events or use mousedown / mouseup instead, I am out of time to test it on Android for the moment.

Comment: i tried mouseover it is not working in same case and onclick is to slow.although it's speed is good in computer browser but bad in mobile

Answer (score 2):

Here an example moving all directions and border checking:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas><br>
<button type="button" onclick="moveRect(0, -10);">move up</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="moveRect(-10, 0);">move left</button>
<button type="button" onclick="moveRect(+10, 0);">move right</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="moveRect(0, +10);">move down</button>
```

JS:

```
var c = null, ctx = null, x = 0, y = 0;
var width = 150, height = 75;

function moveRect(x2, y2) {
    ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
    x += x2;
    if (x < 0) x = 0;
    else if (x > c.width - width) x = c.width - width;
    y += y2;
    if (y < 0) y = 0;
    else if (y > c.height - height) y = c.height - height;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

window.onload = function() {
    c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    x = 0;
    moveRect(0, 0);
}
```

CSS:

```
#canvas {
    width: 200;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yDnBR/).

Answer (score 0):

You can to give fill style to make your rectangle visible or draw it border. Secondly you want to attach event to button to move the rectangle drawn on canvas. The could be done by this code and could mold the code according to your need. [Demo on JsFiddle using Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/8YSX9/) and [Demo on JsFiddle using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUFvd/2/)

```
x =200;
$('#as').click(function()
{    
    var inc=10;
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    //c.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");    


    ctx.fillStyle="#ff0000";    
    ctx.fillRect(x+5,0,15,75);


    ctx.fillStyle="#ffffff";    
    ctx.fillRect(x,0,15,75);
    x-=5;
}
);​
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding and I modified my answer I hope its ok now.